# unable to change the account reference inside the contact using sdk in crm2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am unable to change the client by updating the contact using crm 2011 sdk.Here is the code i am using to do that :

```cs
Entity contact = new Entity();
contact.LogicalName = "contact";            
contact.Attributes = new AttributeCollection();            
EntityReference clientLookup = new EntityReference();
clientLookup.Id = NewClientBId;
clientLookup.LogicalName = "account";
contact.Attributes.Add("parentcustomerid", clientLookup);
contact.Attributes.Add("contactid", workItem.Id);
SynchronousUtility.UpdateDynamicEntity(CrmConnector.Service, contact);
```

The code runs fine without any error but when i go to web portal and check the record ,it still points to the old account though updated the modofication time stamp.I also checked the sql profiler query which shows up as below :

> exec sp_executesql N'update [ContactBase] set
>   [ModifiedOn]=@ModifiedOn0, [ModifiedBy]=@ModifiedBy0,
>   [ModifiedOnBehalfBy]=NULL where ([ContactId] =
>   @ContactId0)',N'@ModifiedOn0 datetime,@ModifiedBy0
>   uniqueidentifier,@ContactId0
>   uniqueidentifier',@ModifiedOn0='2013-07-04
>   09:21:02',@ModifiedBy0='2F8D969F-34AB-E111-9598-005056947387',@ContactId0='D80ACC4E-A185-E211-AB64-002324040068'

as can be seen above the column i have updated is not even there in the set clause of the update query.Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Just to add to it , it is not a problem with the account only.I cant change any other information on the contact.

Comment: values of `Contact_EntityName`,`Custome_EntityName`,`CustomerIdColumnNameInContact`,`ContactIdentityColumn`?

Comment: Just updated my question with constant variable values Guido Preite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it works:

```cs
Entity contact = new Entity();
contact.LogicalName = "contact";
contact.Attributes = new AttributeCollection();
EntityReference clientLookup = new EntityReference();
clientLookup.Id = new Guid("3522bae7-5ae5-e211-9d27-b4b52f566dbc");
clientLookup.LogicalName = "account";
contact.Attributes.Add("parentcustomerid", clientLookup);
contact.Attributes.Add("contactid", new Guid("16dc4143-5ae5-e211-9d27-b4b52f566dbc"));
```

As you can see I used existing Id in my environment, and to perform the update I used

```cs
service.Update(contact);
```

Reasons why your code is not working:

- `NewClientBId` is not the right account Guid
- `workItem.Id` is not the right contact Guid
- the function `SynchronousUtility.UpdateDynamicEntity` has errors

Comment: Thanks Guido .Function SynchronousUtility.UpdateDynamicEntity seems to be working for all the other entites.Also one more thing to point out here is that in order to update , the code inside the SynchronousUtility.UpdateDynamicEntity method calls the execute method of OrganisationServiceProxy which may be the issue.I guess it should be calling the update method.

Comment: Infact the code was fine.The issue was with a synchronous plugin which was bypassing the call if the call to change the client initiates from a interface not known to the plugin :) (Workflow).I had to pass another attribute to set the caller origin info (custom one) to make this work.Thanks for your help.